# ImportError: No module named flask_wtf

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am getting the error, `ImportError: No module named flask_wtf`. I tried every possible solution. I installed flask-wrf using -

`$ flask/bin/pip install flask-wtf`

```
Requirement already satisfied: flask-wtf in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in ./flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages.
```

Please help me out with this issue.

I am sharing my code which shows error:

```
from flask_wtf import Form 
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
    
class LoginForm(Form):
    openid = StringField('openid', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)
```

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? Are you possibly installing `flask_wtf` globally instead of in a virtualenv?  Also I think you need `from flask_wtf import FlaskForm` but that won't give you a module error

Comment: can you share full Traceback log?

Comment: Try `from flask.ext.wtf import Form`

Comment: yes i am using virtualenv and i also tried **from flask_wtf import FlaskForm**  and i even also tried **from flask.ext.wtf import Form**

Comment: @Tiny.D Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/kanishka/projects/microblog/app/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/home/kanishka/projects/microblog/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .forms import LoginForm
  File "/home/kanishka/projects/microblog/app/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import Form
ImportError: No module named flask_wtf

Comment: yes i am using virtualenv

Answer (score 19):

I also have same issue. But installing Flask-WTF

```
pip install flask-wtf
```

I was able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure you run the virtual environment's python rather than global python.  I resolved this in my windows env through executing:

```
\inetpub\projectFolder\scripts\python.exe run.py
```

rather than just

```
python run.py
```

Also, make sure that you have installed the modules to the virtual environment rather than globally.  Check that the modules exist appropriately - again under windows I checked for the file:

```
\inetpub\projectFolder\lib\site-packages\wtforms
```

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly a problem with virtual environment. I had the same problem and managed to get rid of errors with `sudo pip install Flask-WTF` while my virtual environment was active.

This solution, however, has got me into another package (email_validator) importing errors, though I was sure everything is installed as it should be. Now, instead of running `flask run` from terminal, I decided to run the whole application as it, by typing `python3 application.py` in my app directory, where application.py is my flask app.

In this way of running application I haven't come into any errors at all. If you want to run your app like me, be sure to set following conditional at the bottom of your application:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

(This will run your application in debug mode.)

I'm beginner level developer. It would be really nice for someone more experienced to explain logic behind this.

Edit:
Once I ran my application like this, suddenly I can run it with `flask run` again, without any errors. Interesting.

Comment: Just want to echo @pawelduzy with my experience. Running `python app.py` seemed to solve my ImportError after `flask run`. Not sure where the cause was but in case this might be helpful to someone.

Comment: I tried all the other solutions but running python app_name.py was the only one that cleared up the error for me.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Flask-WTF is simple with pip:

```
pip install Flask-WTF
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the top answer

Answer (score 2):

i did simple installation from flask_wtf and it worked the command is following

pip install Flask-WTF

please go to this link for more info
https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Answer (score 2):

In my case it worked *after* I installed it using pip3 instead of just pip.  I didn't look into it enough to find out what was different but I'm seriously thinking of linking pip to pip3 in my venv.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. The problem in my case was that Flask was installed globally , so `flask run` called the global package that didn't recognise the local package (Probably because the global call to python called python2, and my env was set to python3) . I solved it by uninstalling Flask globally and installing it only in the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem
Solved it using following

```
conda install -c wakari flask-wtf
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using Anaconda's python to run your app then you have to `pip install flask-wtf` from the Anaconda prompt and not from general command prompt. This helped me when I encountered this problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could install flask_wtf in conda using this command

```
conda install -c anaconda flask-wtf
```

Since your problem is due to virtualenv, installing this on conda will solve the problem. It did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the python version, i tried all of the above proposition, i changed the python version from 3 to 2, and it work perfectly.

```
python2 app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the [@pawelduzy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62990662/5791355) adding a `app.run(debug=True)` resolved the same issue in my virtual environement where Flask-WTF extension was already installed via `pip install flask-wtf`.

This is the content of my `'__init__.py'` file

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
app.run(debug=True)

from app import routes
```

Alternatively you may insert the `app.run(debug=True)` statement into a `.py`-file that launches the main application

```py
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

But be aware of what is mentioned in the Flask's Docs, namely ["Debugging Application Errors"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#debugging-application-errors)

> Having problems getting your application configured for production? If
> you have shell access to your host, verify that you can run your
> application manually from the shell in the deployment environment. Be
> sure to run under the same user account as the configured deployment
> to troubleshoot permission issues. You can use Flask’s builtin
> development server with `debug=True` on your production host, which is
> helpful in catching configuration issues, but **be sure to do this
> temporarily in a controlled environment.** Do not run in production with
> `debug=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'".
This worked for me:

1. Open Anaconda - install flask_wtf in using this command in the Anaconda terminal:

   ```
   conda install -c anaconda flask-wtf
   ```
2. In Pycharm go to preferences/project/python interpreter. Click the "+" button on the lower left then search for "flask-wtf. Then install the package.

The second step was not possible without the first, since `flask-wtf` didn't show up in the list of available packages.